# java: package org.springframework.context does not exist

Tags: java, spring

I am a beginner in spring, and I try to write a spring-aop project in idea like this:

```
package com.hjh.service;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class AccountServiceTest {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
    ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");
    AccountService accountService=  context.getBean("accountService",AccountService.class);
    accountService.SaveAccount();

}
}
```

but I got:
Error:(2, 35) java: package org.springframework.context does not exist

however I am sure I already import this package:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzFKu.png)

is there anybody have idea about my situation?

Comment: Are you using `maven`? Please provide more details? Do you have the source code on gitHub?